# CDI failure with Dependent/applicatio Scope class

Tags: dependency-injection, jax-rs, cdi

I am trying to Inject `ServletContext` in my dependant scope class but it always gives the failure.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CXF message usable for JAX-RS @Context injections in that thread so can't use interface javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

I am not able to undestand the reason that why can't I inject it here. I am using a producer method and when inside producer method,I try to access `ServletContext` obj then it gives above exception. I have also checked if the Injected servlet context is null but it is not null. But When I call any method using it for example `sc.getContextPath()` it gives the above exception. Below is the code snippet:

```
@Dependent
public class AuthContexthandler {

  @Context
  ServletContext sc;

  @Produces
  JWTAuthContextInfo getInfo() {
    try{
      System.out.println(sc.getContextPath()); //here I get the above mentioned error
      //rest of the code
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think, if you Use inject annotion instead of context annotation, it will work

Comment: Yes, It did. Post it as a answer but Can you please explain why is it so? I am lost all in CDI concepts !!

Comment: When I learned CDI and JAX-RS I was also quite confused by the dependency injection (DI) concepts until I released that JAX-RS has its own DI mechanism which uses not the same annotations as CDI. This results in applications having  beans that are managed by JAX-RS and other's which are managed by CDI. As both frameworks use different annotations for marking beans and injection points you need to make sure that you use the correct annotations. In your example the class `AuthContextHandler` is a CDI bean (because of the `@Dependent` annotaion) while `@Context` marks a JAX-RS injection point.

Comment: @ChristophBöhme makes sense now !! Well explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use @inject instead of @Context.

you can use @Context to inject object instances related to the context of HTTP requests into to JAX-RS source class and as AuthContextHandler(as @Christoph Böhme said) is not a JAX-RS source class so you cannot use @Context

but as http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/ says:

> An object bound to a lifecycle context is called a bean. CDI includes
>   built-in support for several different kinds of bean, including the
>   following Java EE component types:
>
> managed beans, and EJB session beans. Both managed beans and EJB
>   session beans may inject other beans. But some other objects, which
>   are not themselves beans in the sense used here, may also have beans
>   injected via CDI. In the Java EE platform, the following kinds of
>   component may have beans injected:
>
> message-driven beans,
>
> interceptors,
>
> servlets,
>
> servlet filters and
>
> servlet event listeners,
>
> JAX-WS service endpoints and handlers,
>
> JAX-RS resources,
>
> providers and javax.ws.rs.core.Application subclasses, and
>
> JSP tag handlers and tag library event listeners.

it means you also can use @Inject annotation in your JAX-RS source class.

there are also some predefined Beans in CDI such as ServletContext that you can use @inject annotation to inject them.

https://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/servlet/latest/reference/en-US/html/injectablerefs.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv004.htm